Chrome Remote Desktop in 24.04
Has anyone managed to get Chrome Remote Desktop working in 24.04?
I have just fresh installed on a KVM container and I'm really struggling to get it running. The .deb installs fine, but when trying to authorise it, I get the following errors (although it still lets me choose an access code):
mark@mark:~$ DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="xxx" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=$(hostname)
[0501/123811.619098:ERROR:host_config.cc(83)] Failed to read /home/mark/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/host#ea82410c7a9991816b5eeeebe195e20a.json
[0501/123811.619379:ERROR:usage_stats_consent_linux.cc(31)] No host config file found.
Enter a PIN of at least six digits: 
Enter the same PIN again: 
[0501/123820.196691:ERROR:host_config.cc(83)] Failed to read /home/mark/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/host#ea82410c7a9991816b5eeeebe195e20a.json
[0501/123820.351170:ERROR:host_starter_base.cc(305)] Failed to exchange the authorization_code due to an OAuth error.
Couldn't start host: OAuth error.

I have used CRD in Ubuntu since 2020 without any problems, including multiple reinstalls with 20.04 and 22.04.
This is an alternative error I also get on different attempts:
mark@mark:~$ DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="xxx" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=$(hostname)
[0501/125439.889574:ERROR:host_config.cc(83)] Failed to read /home/mark/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/host#ea82410c7a9991816b5eeeebe195e20a.json
[0501/125439.890030:ERROR:usage_stats_consent_linux.cc(31)] No host config file found.
Enter a PIN of at least six digits: 
Enter the same PIN again: 
[0501/125445.333032:ERROR:host_config.cc(83)] Failed to read /home/mark/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/host#ea82410c7a9991816b5eeeebe195e20a.json
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Any help appreciated!

I downgraded to 22.04.4 and I get the same problem there. I think CRD is broken for now - it updated yesterday it seems.

Same problem. I solved it by downloading the old version of the application.
https://deb.rug.nl/ppa/mirror/dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb/pool/main/c/chrome-remote-desktop/
Same error, but the application starts.
Or Official Repository:
https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb/pool/main/c/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop_124.0.6367.18_amd64.deb
